# How to exclude certain times between two dates?

Tags: mysql

there is problem, that this query excludes all dates and times between 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-14, but I want to exclude all dates between 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-14 and times only from 13:30:00 to 15:00:00, how can I achieve this?

```
select `id`, `rental_schedule_status`, `date`, `time_from`, `time_to` 
from `rental_schedules` where `premises_id` = 1 and `public_enterprise` = 0
and `date` between '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-28' 
and (`date` not BETWEEN '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-14' 
and ((`time_from` < '13:30:00') or (`time_to` > '15:00:00')))
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Replace your last `and` with an `or`

Comment: WHERE specifies the rows to be included. So your "I want to exclude all dates between 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-14 and times only from 13:30:00 to 15:00:00" must be converted to: where date is not between 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-14, or the time is not between 13:30:00 to 15:00:00.

Comment: what is the data type for 'date' and 'time_from' columns?

Comment: DATE and TIME accordingly